# Creating a new Jenkins X login

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-x

How do I create a new Jenkins X login, i.e. a username and password to get into the Jenkins X GUI? It looks like Jenkins X has a different concept of User (Git user?).

I ran

`jx create user --login someUsername`

But can't see a new user created via the Jenkins GUI, but have seem some users magically created from previous Git commits.

Since this is Jenkins X, *Security Realm* has been set to *Delegate to servlet container* and so I have no obvious way to manage users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We default to the kubernetes RBAC in Jenkins X for most things.

You can configure the Jenkins Server via helm to tweak things like authentication and the like: https://jenkins-x.io/getting-started/config/

We also have instructions on how to add a user to your Jenkins X installation: https://jenkins-x.io/faq/setup/#how-do-i-add-a-user-to-my-jenkins-x-installation